# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException @$Proxy21 error in Java Appium PageFactory initElements

Tags: java, appium

I have suddenly started facing below error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: If you use a '@$Proxy21' annotation, you must not also use a '@$Proxy23' annotation
>   at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.checkDisallowedAnnotationPairs(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:46)
>     at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.assertValidAnnotations(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:87)

I am using below code to init elements:

```
  PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(appiumDriver, 6, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);
```

It was working all fine & without any major changes its now failing.

Appium version: 1.7.1

My POM.xml

```
   <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.java.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.extentsreport.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>${appium.java-client.version}</version>
        <!--<version>5.0.0-BETA5</version>-->
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>${json-path.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.monte.screenrecorder</groupId>
        <artifactId>MonteScreenRecorder</artifactId>
        <version>10</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/monte-screen-recorder-0.7.7.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${json-simple.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
    <!--<dependency>-->
    <!--<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>-->
    <!--<artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>-->
    <!--<version>3.3.1</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>${spring-context.version}</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest-library.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--Exploratory Cucumber-TestNG Fusion-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>1.2.4</version>-->
        <!--<scope>compile</scope>-->
        <!--<exclusions>-->
            <!--<exclusion>-->
                <!--<groupId>junit</groupId>-->
                <!--<artifactId>junit</artifactId>-->
            <!--</exclusion>-->
        <!--</exclusions>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->


    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>${cucumber-spring.version}</version>-->
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>-->
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>-->
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit5-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-ALPHA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.testobject</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>testobject-appium-java-api</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>0.1.0</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>browserstack-local-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>report.donut</groupId>
        <artifactId>donut</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>automate-testassist</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>0.7.2-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>browserstack-integration</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>LATEST</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

</dependencies>
```

I am not able to figure out why I have suddenly started to get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use latest client library, which is **5.0.4** since you are on Appium 1.7.1.

Clean maven cache from `.m2\repository` and install dependencies from scratch.

It also maybe the case you mixed incompatible annotations while defining some element. Check here for [working examples](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/pagefactory_tests/MobileBrowserCompatibilityTest.java)